# How can I display a truncated URL with the link_to helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How would I truncate a url submitted from a form? Here is what I am using to display the submitted url:

index view:

```
<%= link_to gym.gym_website.try(:remove, /.*\/\//), url_for(gym.gym_website), target: '_blank', class: '' %>
```

How would I add the truncate method onto this? I am currently removing http/https from the submitted url.

```
<%= truncate(gym.gym_website, :escape => false, :length => 45) %>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is in `gym_website`?

Comment: @RSB it's just the name of my form field <%= f.text_field :gym_website, class: "", placeholder: "facility website" %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `block` version of the `link_to` helper for readability here.

```
<%= link_to url_for(gym.gym_website), target: '_blank', class: '' do %>
  <%= truncate(gym.gym_website.try(:remove, /.*\/\//), :escape => false, :length => 45) %>
<% end %>
```